# Shifting image in a vrt

Tags: gdal, gdalbuildvrt

I have a set of geotif images that I want shifted by an integer number of pixels in X and Y. However, those images are quite large, so I don't want to duplicate them (and I need to keep the original unmodified), so modifying the geotransform is not a solution for me.

Is it possible to create a set of vrts (with different shift values) without modifying or duplicating the original images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be easy at least with non-rotated images which use metric units. Create VRT file and edit the 1st and 4th parameters of GeoTransform by hand.

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="12000" rasterYSize="12000">
  <GeoTransform> 3.8100000000000000e+005, 5.0000000000000000e-001, 0.0000000000000000e+000, 6.8270000000000000e+006, 0.0000000000000000e+000,-5.0000000000000000e-001</GeoTransform>
```

The image below shows the same image opened through the original and edited .VRT with 1000 m shifts.

[image: Shifted by editing .VRT]

I have also a feeling that if PAM metadata is present as .aux.xml file GDAL will use it instead of the internal georeferencing of GeoTIFF. However, I can't say directly how to create the aux.xml metadata file for existing GeoTIFFs.